# VS code prettier adds unwanted curly brackets / blocks {" "}

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, prettier

#### Famous [Visual Studio code prettier plugin](https://github.com/prettier/prettier-vscode) adds extra `{" "}` when performing formatting.

**Explanation:**

This does not happen always. I work on React Native, that is `JavaScript`. If prettier finds space in my code, it will convert space in unwanted `{" "}`.

**See example**

I had this line in my code.

```
Item Total {getPriceText(this.calculateTotal(
                this.state.extraItem.extras
              ))}
```

When i format code then it is converted into this.

```
 Item Total{" "}
                  {getPriceText(
                    this.calculateTotal(this.state.extraItem.extras)
                  )}
```

**This makes my code buggy, and it makes run time crashes my app.** Which i solve by finding these extra brackets in my code.

**Any solutions please?**

Comment: there is a bug report on this already: 
 https://github.com/prettier/prettier/issues/4223

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the question is asking to fix a problem with a 3rd party library which already has a bug report filed regarding the issue.  https://github.com/prettier/prettier/issues/4223